# Java Jung Degree Sequences

Tags: java, graph, sequence, jung, degrees

I am doing some Graph Theory analysis using the Java Jung 2.01 graph package. I am looking for some sort of function that will give me a degree sequence of the graph. I have been poking around the Jung documentation but do not see anything.

1. How can I retrieve the degree sequence of a graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, `JUNG` does not have such functionality. You could however loop over all nodes, retrieve all degrees and sort them accordingly. You could suggest it to the developing community over at their [forums](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jung/forums/forum/252062).

Comment: It's unlikely that we'd ever add this to the library, since it's so trivial.  You don't even have to sort them as a separate step, just add them to a `SortedSet` with an appropriate `Comparator`.

Comment: If you have a lot of nodes, I would still go for sorting them all at once. If you use a sortedset, you are basically doing insertion sort. If you sort them all at once, you can use better sorting algorithms and lower the complexity.

Comment: SortedSet is backed by a tree, so the complexity is O(n lg n) either way.  Whether it's faster to use a SortedSet or to copy the vertices and their degrees into a separate data structure and then sort it is left as an exercise for profilers.  :)  Also, SortedSet gives you ranges and so forth, which might be helpful.